# aws Ec2 Container registry (When deployed using kubernetes Image cannot be pulled due to auth credentials)

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes, aws-ecr

- I have created my cluster using kubeadm init and even provided the config file to define the cloud provider as aws.
- I have given the required permission for the IAM role for ECR and i am able to pull the image using the docker pull.
- It's just when i deploy my pod via kubernetes it cannot pull the images.

Is there something that i am missing?

Following is the description of the POD.

```
Events:
  Type     Reason                 Age              From                                    Message
  ----     ------                 ----             ----                                    -------
  Normal   Scheduled              4m               default-scheduler                       Successfully assigned red to ip-192-31-94-118.ec2.internal
  Normal   SuccessfulMountVolume  4m               kubelet, ip-192-31-94-118.ec2.internal  MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "default-token-fv9mk"
  Normal   SandboxChanged         4m               kubelet, ip-192-31-94-118.ec2.internal  Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
  Normal   Pulling                3m (x3 over 4m)  kubelet, ip-192-31-94-118.ec2.internal  pulling image "ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/testapp:latest"
  Warning  Failed                 3m (x3 over 4m)  kubelet, ip-192-31-94-118.ec2.internal  Failed to pull image "ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/testapp:latest": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v2/testapp/manifests/latest: no basic auth credentials
  Warning  Failed                 3m (x3 over 4m)  kubelet, ip-192-31-94-118.ec2.internal  Error: ErrImagePull
  Normal   BackOff                2m (x7 over 4m)  kubelet, ip-192-31-94-118.ec2.internal  Back-off pulling image "ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/testapp:latest"
  Warning  Failed                 2m (x7 over 4m)  kubelet, ip-192-31-94-118.ec2.internal  Error: ImagePullBackOff
```

Comment: It may be dumb, but is ECR offered in your region ?
Is the kubelet running with `--cloud-provider=aws` ?

Comment: Yes i am using us-east-1 region

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you configure Kubernetes with ECR on AWS, you can stumble in two places:

IAM Roles:

Make sure you add permissions to **ALL** Kubernetes nodes to pull images from ECR.

Cloud Provider:
Make sure your kubelet runs with `--cloud-provider=aws`parameter.

In your case, you are sure all run correctly, so you missed IAM permission on some Kubernetes node.

Comment: `kubeadm config view | grep cloud    
cloudProvider: aws`  

I have given all the IAM Roles for ECR for the instances 
Yet I am having the problem